# How to make Microsoft Word ignore paper tray settings?

Tags: printing, microsoft-office

Some printer settings are saved inside Microsoft Word documents. The selected paper tray is one of them (could be the only one, as I don't remember seeing anything else, but maybe double-sided printing too).

1. create a word document
2. select a specific paper tray, then print it to a shared printer
3. save the document
4. open the document on another computer
5. print it to the same shared printed
   --> the specific paper tray is used

The problem is when a Word document is received from a "foreign" source (aka someone with a different printer, or a different paper tray setup). The user expects the document to be printed on the default paper tray. This often lead to waste of time and paper, because the user see the headed paper used for whatever email printed for reference.

--> how to make Word ignore paper tray settings recorded into the document?